# Combine SpqrkSQL and GraphX

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, apache-spark, spark-graphx

Can you create a stored procedure in SparkSQL and call GraphX API? something like this:

`registerFunction("storedProcedureGraphX", model.storedProcedureGraphX _)`

`select * from someTable where storedProcedureGraphX(nodeX, nodeY) > 10`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by *GraphX API* you mean any operation on RDD then the answer is no. That would involve launching new Spark task for each row which definitely isn't a good idea. And you'd have to close on the `SparkContext`, which is not serializable - and functions that you use as UDFs have to be.